# DNN - How can I edit Client Dependency files to change mappings for a specific JQuery resource file?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have a Dot Net Nuke  (DNN 9.1) site which is hosted on IIS. I have located some resources that have made the website very slow, mostly JS / CSS files. I traced these files are referenced in resource files like below:

**Website\App_Data\ClientDependency\DNNWeb-someGUIDaaarfgxetrrcxxdrwdc-map.xml**

which has entriees like below:

```
  <item key="678f2dbfsdg- some key -dtgsdt54fdfgy7" file="" compression="" version="180">
        <files>
          <file name="/Resources/libraries/jQuery/01_09_01/jquery.js" />
          <file name="/Resources/libraries/jQuery-UI/01_11_03/jquery-ui.js" />
        </files>
  </item>
```

I need to modify mapings so the minimized version of JS files may be used, to enhance performance (e.g. *jquery.min.js*), however, its being said that this XML file gets regenerated if modified manually, and my changes will be lost.

Any thoughts or help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNN loads minified CSS and JS files based on user config. you need to enable this options, the options are

- Enable Composite Files
- Minify CSS
- Minify JS

In order to change above settings go to `Settings (gear icon) -> Servers -> Server Settings Tab -> Performance tab`, then find `Client Resources Management Mode` section (at the bottom of this tab (*as of `v9.5`*)) and change the options as you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's easy, open up any page of your site and hit `Ctrl+U` (or right click and select View page source from the menu), look for `jQuery`, you should see the `script` tag and value of `src` attribute is the location you are looking for. (e.g: `/Resources/libraries/jQuery/03_04_01/jquery.js`)

Comment: Great instructions. Is there a way to find out where in DNN are physical JS files (e.g. JQUERY) actually referenced? Within the solution, the only place I can see these files is *map.XML - which is said to be re-generated by DNN.. I need to know this so I can point it to a different file and change references.

Comment: @David I answered this question in my prev comment. do you want to change jquery version in your site?

Comment: Sure, if you can instruct how to change JavaScript library version in DNN, I will add it to my post below for future readers.

Comment: Making another folder inside `/Resources/libraries/jQuery`, e.g: `03_04_02` and change the version of jQuery via `JavaScript libraries` doesn't work? I didn't test this solution

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The following setting allows CDN references for JavaScript libraries. [Thanks to Michael Tobisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516132/dnn-how-can-i-add-cdn-cloud-references-for-bootstrap-jquery-files/60540544#60540544)

Settings >> Extensions, select JavaScript Libraries from the dropdown list, click the pencil next to the JavaScript jQuery library, select the Extension Settings tab and enter the Url in the Custom CDN setting.

[image]